# Opening View Controller is extremely slow on Appium

Tags: ios, appium-ios, xcuitest

In my app, instantiating and pushing view controller is extremely slow means it's taking 5+ minutes. Tested on simulator only.

**Code:**

```
@IBAction fileprivate func locationButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if (mSelectLocationVC == nil)
        {
            mSelectLocationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectLocationViewController") as? SelectLocationViewController
            mSelectLocationVC?.delegate = self
        }         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mSelectLocationVC!, animated: true)
}
```

**Capabilities:**

"platformName": "iOS", 
"platformVersion": "11.3",
"deviceName": "iPhone 6",
"automationName": "XCUITest",
"app": "/Users/xxx/Documents/Downloads/iOSApp.app",
"autoAcceptAlerts": true,
"autoDismissAlerts": true,
"autoGrantPermissions": true,
"databaseEnabled": true

Please help!!!

Comment: add code of `SelectLocationViewController`

Comment: Sorry Pratik, but cannot share code as it's not allowed by the company. Few details are settings elements in viewDidLoad and database call in viewWillAppear. There is no API/server call.

Comment: In `SelectLocationViewController`, may be some code run in main thread than need to be run in background thread, check your code.

Comment: Actually, In simulator view controller is opening very fast but in Appium inspector, its taking time. So, is there any issue with Appium. I hope you got my point.